# How can I be sure that BitBucket will do merge (with website button)?

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket, git-merge

Let Alice and Bob works on the same BitBucket git repository. Alice has admin privileges, while Bob has the restriction to write on master branch. So each time Bob want to contribute, he makes a special branch, commits to it and then do a Pull Request.

Alice prefer GUI while Bob is OK with command line.

Question: what way Bob can be sure that Alice would be able to do a merge from BitBucket website GUI button?

P.S. Or maybe there is other workflow for this situation? When Alice should control all changes to master branch and whats to accepts Pull Requests via button.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how Bob can predict whether there will be merge conflicts that must be resolved?

Comment: @Chris, yes, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> what way Bob can be sure that Alice would be able to do a merge from BitBucket website GUI button?

Bob has to make sure his branch is based on the latest version of master, in order for a pull request to result in a trivial fast-forward merge of his branch into master.

So before pushing, always rebasing on top of master:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force
```

(Since Bob is the only one working on his branch, changing the history won't be an issue, and force pushing is fine: the pull request, if created before, will adjust to the new history of that branch)

Comment: By fetching, the local master branch will remain unmerged with origin/master. You would either need to do a `git pull` instead of a `git fetch` or use `git rebase origin/master` instead of `git rebase master`.

Comment: @benjic Sure, I must have blanked on the rebase command there. I have edited the answer.